# Getting 500 Internal Server Error while using WebAPI 2 and CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am creating web-services using Web-API 2. I've Enabled Cross-origin resource sharing using following code.

Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </handlers>
<httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" /> </customHeaders> </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer></configuration>
```

APIController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using ProActiveWebServices.Models;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;

namespace ProActiveWebServices.Controllers
{

    public class EnquiryController : ApiController
    {
        ProActiveEntities db = new ProActiveEntities();
        List<Enquiry> en = new List<Enquiry> { };
        List<City> ct = new List<City> { };
        EnquiryList enquiryList = new EnquiryList();
        CityList cityList = new CityList();

        // GET api/<controller>
        [Route("api/GetAllEnquiry")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            try
            {
                if (CheckAuthentication(Request) || 1==1)
                {
                    var enquiry = db.tbl_Enquiry.ToList();
                    foreach (var e in enquiry)
                    {
                        Enquiry _enquiry = new Enquiry();
                        _enquiry.FullName = e.FullName;
                        _enquiry.Id = e.EnquiryID;
                        _enquiry.CompanyName = e.CompanyName;
                        _enquiry.ContactAddress = e.ContactAddress;
                        _enquiry.Email = e.Email;
                        _enquiry.fk_CityID = e.fk_CityID;
                        _enquiry.Comment = e.Comment;
                        en.Add(_enquiry);
                    }
                    enquiryList.EnquiryLists = en;
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Enquiry = enquiryList });
                    return response;
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { Error = "Invalid Header and Authorization" });
                    return response;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error:" + ex.ToString());
                return response;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my WebAPIConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace ProActiveWebServices
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I run it on localhost, It is working all fine. but when host the web-service on godaddy, I am getting 500-Internal server error.
I have enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin in web.config also. but still no success

Comment: Are you getting 500 for OPTIONS request (it would imply something related to Verbs in Web.Config) or for actual GET/POST request? Disabling custom errors should let you see full callstack - use Fiddler to intercept and inspect requests and post the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

This was required for me to get my service going on GoDaddy.

Add the following to your web.config (there are some drawbacks to adding this line to your web.config, do some research as I can't recall exactly but theres heaps on info about it if you google):

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

You may also have to add

```
<system.web>
    <securityPolicy>
         <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal" />
     </securityPolicy>
     <trust level="Full" originUrl="" processRequestInApplicationTrust="true" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered this error if you are using web api and enabling Cors by EnableCors in web config then you dont need to write it again in web  config.

writing this one in you web api config would do if you dont have any unhandled exception in your code

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
                origins: "*",
                headers: "*",
                methods: "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```